# C++ Basic Class Constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I'm going through a C++ course right now, and they're doing a good job of over-explaining everything until it comes to splitting the files up between header "promises" and implementation. I learned programming entirely in Python so I'm used to just declaring things outright and importing the class as necessary, so this whole separating a promise and then implementing logic is strange to me.

Anyway, I'm having trouble because in the course they were saying you never actually need to use `this->` but when I'm trying to define a class explicitly in the same .cpp file, I can only get the constructor to work when I use `this->`. Can someone please explain or link a discussion that explains this? I haven't been able to find a reference that explains this issue in the context of defining everything in the same file.

```
class Person {
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
    Person (string name, int age, int height, int weight) {
        name = name;
        age = age;
        height = height;
        weight = weight;
    }   
};

int main () {
    Person new_person("Doug", 20, 70, 170);
}
```

This causes all the values I pass in from the main function to not initialize. However, if I add this-> to each line in the constructor, it works fine. The examples I find don't use `this->` so I'm confused why it's necessary here. Perhaps it has to do with namespaces which are still a little confusing to me (the whole using namespace std; thing) but I thought since it's all in the same .cpp file, this should work.

Comment: name = name - which one belongs to the class and which one is the parameter? To solve this ambiguity you either use this->name or change the variable names: use prefix m_ for data members, for instance: m_name = name.

Comment: Note that the better solution is to use the initializater list, to *initialize* the data members rather than *assign values* to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument variables *overshadow* your member variables in the scope of your constructor. That is, within that context, `name` refers to the input variable only.

What you could do is use an initialization list:

```
Person (string name, int age, int height, int weight) :
    name(name), age(age), height(height), weight(weight) {}
```

Or use different names:

```
Person (string _name, int _age, int _height, int _weight) {
    name = _name;
    age = _age;
    height = _height;
    weight = _weight;
}
```

But your approach using `this->` is totally fine.

You might also want to read http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/using-this-in-ctors.html

Comment: Ahh!! So simple, but i'm so used to matching parameter names to attribute names in Python such as `self.name = name` that I completely overlooked this subtle (yet massive) difference. The course definitely glazed over this and just kind of assumes you can figure it out, but did not explain really how a constructor works from start to finish.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz Matching the names is not a bad practice. If I can use it, I prefere the initialization list method. Another thing I often do is to give the member a slightly different name in order for a method that returns it to have that name, like `string name() const { return m_name; }`, with a member in hungarian notation, or even, like in python for "private" members, just with an underscore: `_name`.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz that was the deal with original version of C++... it became too tedious, especially with large structures.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz "_but i'm so used to matching parameter names to attribute names in Python such as `self.name = name`_" The equivalent of `self.name = name` in C++ is `this->name = name`.

Comment: The second approach is inefficient or impossible in the general case. And the first should make full use of move-semantics to achieve best performance and guarantee success.

Comment: The initialiser list is often considered better practice in C++, for various reasons.   It initialises members on construction of an instance rather than two steps of default initialising and then reassigning the members in the constructor body.   However, in the interests of clarity/readability, it is sometimes advised to have the name of constructor arguments differ from name of members in the initialiser list.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need `this` because you are using the same name for both your constructor parameters and class members.

```
Person (string name, int age, int height, int weight) {
    this->name = // this-> means the member variable
        name;    // just the parameter
```

If you had a different name for your parameter `this` would not be necessary

```
Person (string name_, int age, int height, int weight) {
    name =      // the member variable
        name_;  // the parameter
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the other answer because it was pretty much identical, but posted first. This perfectly clarified what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Only problem with `->this` approach is that it is A) wordy  b) doesn't initialize object. c) makes this object non-trivial.

Proper initializing constructor would look like this, using initialization list:

```
Person (string nm, int ag, int ht, int wt): 
    name(nm), age(ag), height(ht), weight(wt) {}
```

It's not really same as doing what you do, in this case object can be created statically without performing any actions. Your implementation of class always performs assignments. C++11 and later allows to do away with fully trivial implementation:

```
class Person {
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;

    void do_stuff() {};
};

// let's assume that string is std::string, 
// creation from  const char* and = are defined
int main()
{
  Person p = { "Nemo", 35, 5, 120 };
  Person p2 = p;
  p = { "John-117", 24, 6, 170 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was pretty certain I could do it without any constructor but I was using parentheses still rather than assigning a list with the braces. This makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a case of *ambiguity of dependent names*. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name):

> If the lookup of a member of current instantiation gives a different
>   result between the point of instantiation and the point of definition,
>   the lookup is ambiguous. Note however that when a member name is used,
>   it is not automatically converted to a class member access expression,
>   only explicit member access expressions indicate members of current
>   instantiation:

[Eli Bendersky writes eloquently](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates) about this. An excerpt:

> All you have to do is to make the compiler understand that the call f depends on the template parameter T. A couple of ways to do this are replacing f() with **Base::f()**, or with **this->f()** (since this is implicitly dependent on T).

So your own *`this->` solution* is more than fine : )